# TypeError: date[("get" + method)] is not a function in React-big-calendar

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, react-router, react-big-calendar

I am trying to change the view from month to week but in meantime it give me an error . I am new to react and react-big-calendar could someone please help me how to solve this problem . When I change calendar view to month it working fine but when I changed it to week or day so it give me an error. please help me Thanks

**Code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import MyCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
import CustomToolbar from './toolbar';
import Popup from 'react-popup';
import Input from './input';
import moment from 'moment';
import { fetchEvents, createEvent, updateEvent, deleteEvent } from '../actions';


// Setup the localizer by providing the moment (or globalize) Object to the correct localizer.
const localizer = MyCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment); // or globalizeLocalizer

class Calendar extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchEvents();
    }

    //RENDER SINGLE EVENT POPUP CONTENT
    renderEventContent(slotInfo) {
        const date = moment(slotInfo.start).format('MMMM D, YYYY');
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Date: <strong>{date}</strong></p>
                <p>Subject: {slotInfo.taskChage}</p>
                <p>Time : {slotInfo.time}</p>
                <p>Date : { slotInfo.date}</p>
                <p>Notes : {slotInfo.notes}</p>
                <p>User Id : {slotInfo.userId}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }

    //ON SELECT EVENT HANDLER FUNCTION
    onSelectEventHandler = (slotInfo) => {
        Popup.create({
            title: slotInfo.title,
            content: this.renderEventContent(slotInfo),
            buttons: {
                right: [{
                    text: 'Edit',
                    className: 'info',
                    action: function () {
                        Popup.close(); //CLOSE PREVIOUS POPUP
                        this.openPopupForm(slotInfo); //OPEN NEW EDIT POPUP
                    }.bind(this)
                }, {
                    text: 'Delete',
                    className: 'danger',
                    action: function () {
                        //CALL EVENT DELETE ACTION
                        this.props.deleteEvent(slotInfo.id);
                        Popup.close();
                    }.bind(this)
                }]
            }
        });
    }

    //HANDLE FUNCITON ON SELECT EVENT SLOT
    onSelectEventSlotHandler = (slotInfo) => {
        this.openPopupForm(slotInfo); //OPEN POPUP FOR CREATE/EDIT EVENT
    }

    //POPUP-FORM FUNCTION FOR CREATE AND EDIT EVENT
    openPopupForm = (slotInfo) => {
        let newEvent = false;
        let popupTitle = "Update Event";
        if(!slotInfo.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            slotInfo.id = moment().format('x');  //Generate id with Unix Millisecond Timestamp
            slotInfo.title = null;
            slotInfo.taskChange = null;
            slotInfo.message=null;
            popupTitle = "Create Event";
            newEvent = true;
        }

        let titleChange = function (value) {
            slotInfo.title = value;
        };
        let taskChange = function (value) {
            slotInfo.taskChage = value;
        };

        let timeChange = function (value) {
            slotInfo.time = value;
        };

        let dateChnage = function ( value){
            slotInfo.date=value;
        };


        let notesChange = function ( value){
            slotInfo.notes=value;
        };

        let userId = function ( value){
            slotInfo.userId=value;
        };

        Popup.create({
            title: popupTitle,
            content: <div>
                        <Input onChange={titleChange} placeholder="Subject" />
                        <Input onChange={taskChange} placeholder="Task Type"  />
                        <Input onChange={timeChange} placeholder="Time"/>
                        <Input onChange={dateChnage} placeholder="Date"/>
                        <Input onChange={notesChange} placeholder="Notes"/>
                        <Input onChange={userId} placeholder="User Id"/>
                    </div>,
            buttons: {
                left: ['cancel'],
                right: [{
                    text: 'Save',
                    className: 'success',
                    action: function () {
                        //CHECK THE ID PROPERTY FOR CREATE/UPDATE
                        if(newEvent) {
                            this.props.createEvent(slotInfo); //EVENT CREATE ACTION
                        } else {
                            this.props.updateEvent(slotInfo); //EVENT UPDATE ACTION
                        }
                        Popup.close();
                    }.bind(this)
                }]
            }
        });
    }

    //EVENT STYLE GETTER FOR SLYLING AN EVENT ITEM
    eventStyleGetter(event, start, end, isSelected) {
        let current_time = moment().format('YYYY MM DD');
        let event_time = moment(event.start).format('YYYY MM DD');
        let background = (current_time>event_time) ? '#DE6987' : '#8CBD4C';
        return {
            style: {
                backgroundColor: background
            }
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="calendar-container">
                <MyCalendar
                    popup
                    selectable
                    localizer={localizer}
                    defaultView={MyCalendar.Views.WEEK}
                    components={{toolbar: CustomToolbar}}
                    views={['week']}
                    style={{height: 600}}
                    events={this.props.events}
                    eventPropGetter={(this.eventStyleGetter)}
                    onSelectEvent={(slotInfo) => this.onSelectEventHandler(slotInfo)}
                    onSelectSlot={(slotInfo) => this.onSelectEventSlotHandler(slotInfo)}
                />
                {console.log(this.props.event)}
                <Popup />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        events: state.events
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ 
        fetchEvents, 
        createEvent, 
        updateEvent, 
        deleteEvent
    }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Calendar);
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @CatarinaFerreira TypeError: date[(“get” + method)]

Comment: I am getting the same error. I originally was setting all of my events to `allDay: true` and after changing that to false and switching from month view to week view this error comes up: `d[("get" + method)] is not a function`. The `start` and `end` date values are `moment` objects. The `localizer` on the calendar is `moment` as well.

Answer (score 26):

For anyone finding this, a few things.

Your `localizer` handles manipulation of dates under the hood. All dates that you pass in (from your `getNow` and `date` props, all the way to your individual `event.start` and `event.end` dates) should be true JS `Date` objects.

Your various method props, for working with `events` or setting styling or whatever, will receive true JS `Date` objects, not `localizer` objects or UTC strings or whatever.

RBC will only work with true JS `Date` objects. If you pass it `moment` instances or date strings or something else, it might display but it will operate funky, as RBC will handle all conversions under the hood, and it's use of the `date-arithmatic` library, internally, works with true JS `Date`s and not your `localizer` objects.

Comment: You saved me! Thank you very much. My event's start and end dates were `moment` format. Changed to moment().toDate()`

Comment: The component doesn't work with other date formats. You need to convert the date to javascript's Date() object.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue before. The solution depends on your date field.

If date field is like  start: new Date('2024-09-02T08:00:00-04:00'),
then use this: startAccessor="start"

If date field is like  "start": "2024-01-15T08:00:00-04:00",
then use this: startAccessor={(event) => { return new Date(event.start) }}

In the 2nd case, below will throw same error.
startAccessor={(event) => { return moment(event.start) }}

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. this is what solved me issue. elborating: react-big-calendar expects a Date **OBJECT**, and NOT a string

Comment: 2nd case fixed this for me , thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**const formatted = moment(time).toDate();**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the correct values for `start` and `end` keys in your `event` object,
your `event` object should be like :

```js
data = [
  {
    title: "My event",
    allDay: false,
    start: new Date(2020, 10, 25, 10, 0), // 10.00 AM
    end: new Date(2020, 10, 25, 11, 0), // 2.00 PM
  }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens when the date you are trying to display is "String" when actually "date" is an "Object" type, then you could do something like this:

as event data example convert string to date object.

```
{
  id: 8,
  title: "Meeting",
  start: new Date("2022-05-12T08:00:00.000Z"),
  end: new Date("2022-05-12T09:00:00.000Z")
}
```